# iOS9のATS回避

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone

objective-cでiOSの開発を行っております。
Appleから公開されているXcode7beta4、iPhone6iOS9のエミュレーターで
アプリを起動したところ以下の様なエラーが表示されました。

> CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824) NSURLSession/NSURLConnection
>   HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824) Response json =
>   (null) Request faild name:SSLエラーが起きたため、サーバへのセキュリティ保護された接続を確立できません。

エラーとなっている処理はAppDelegate内からサーバーへAPIを投げております。
原因はiOS9のATSだと考えておりinfo.plistに回避する項目を足しましたが同じエラーが発生します。
info.plistに以下の項目を追加しました。

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

info.plistの内容が反映されないなんてことはあるのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: info.plistに追加した項目の詳細も可能な限り開示したほうが、より的確な回答を得られるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: info.plistに追加した項目を追記しました。